# Testing javascript with QUnit and conditional inclusion

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, qunit, thymeleaf

I would need tips about testing javascript with QUnit.

For instance one needs to include the QUnit library as well as the test file when testing but **those files must not be included in production**.

How can one deal with this issue and **conditionally include those files** possibly using Spring profiles?

For your information, I use Spring + Thymeleaf.

Comment: What are you building your application with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `spring.profiles.active` to toggle the QUnit profile in one of the following places:

- system environment variables
- JVM system properties
- servlet context parameters in web.xml
- JNDI

For example, the web.xml can be set to the production profile:

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
          <param-value>production</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

But the command-line can override it:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="QUnit"
```

**References**

- [Spring 3.1 Environment Profiles](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles)